# Creating custom form field in Joomla 3.6 plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I looking if there is a solution for creating a custom field in the xml file so i tried to create a field

```
<field name="inject_label"
    type="note"
    default="WRAPROTECT_PLG_INJECT_LABEL"
    label="WRAPROTECT_PLG_INJECT_LABEL"
/>
```

Now in my language file i did this

```
WRAPROTECT_PLG_INJECT_LABEL="<div class='control-group'>
<label class='control-label'>.htaccess</label>
<div class='controls'>
<p class='help-block'> %s </p></div>
</div>"
```

In my plugin i want to replace

> %S

by checking

> JRequest::getVar('clean_cache');

and

> sprintf('WRAPROTECT_PLG_INJECT_LABEL',$someVar);

I'm searching if there is a best practice to do this in a different way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my XML file i used

```
<fieldset label="WRAPROTECT_PLG_GLOBAL_LABEL" name="basic_1" addfieldpath="plugins/system/wraprotect/fields">
</fieldset>
```

In my php file i used the function

> getInput()

and

```
return '<tag>'.JText::_('some text %s').'</tag>';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace `%s`, then you can use the following:

```
$jinput  = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$someVar = $jinput->get('clean_cache', '');

echo JText::sprintf('WRAPROTECT_PLG_INJECT_LABEL', $someVar);
```

As you can see, I've made use of `JInput` instead of `JRequest`, as this is deprecated.

Comment: I used a custom type in my xml so i'll paste it in the answer

Answer (score 1):

For creating a custom field in xml, do it as-

provide type ="your_desired_name", like i have given abcd.

Now, create a php file with name abcd.php and place it in 'fields' folder.
Now define a class in it as-

```
<?php

defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;
jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldAbcd extends JFormField {
    protected $type = 'abcd';

    protected function getInput() {
        return 'required value';
    }

}
```